# use flatmap to filter and compute values in a collection

Tags: scala

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to do this:

```
val list = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
list.flatMap(i => if (i % 2 == 0) Some(i * 2) else None)
list.flatMap(i => if (i % 2 == 0) (i * 2) :: Nil else Nil)
```

Both way can return expected result, I'm not sure which way is better. Thanks for your time!

Edit:

I know `list.filter(_ % 2 == 0).map(_ * 2)` is good for this simple case, but my real case is complex, there are more than one accepted conditions for filter and each have its own handle function for filtered element.

Comment: Idiomatic way is `list.filter(_ % 2 == 0)`

Comment: `Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).filter(_ % 2 != 0).map(_ * 2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multiple filter conditions and associated computations, you can try something like this.

```
  val list = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 

  list.collect {
    case i if (i % 2 == 0) => i * 2
    case i if (i % 3 == 0) => i * 3
    case i if (i % 5 == 0) => i * 5
  }                   //> res0: Seq[Int] = List(4, 9, 8, 25, 12)
```

You can add a default `case` if you need to do something with elements that don't match. If you do that, you might as well use `map` instead of `collect` since the function that is the case statements is no longer a partial function.